# Why is $n^\sqrt n - 2^n \to - \infty$ and $\sqrt n ^n - 2^n \to +\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can you explain technically why the following limits are correct?

$$n^\sqrt n - 2^n \to - \infty$$ and $$\sqrt n ^n - 2^n \to +\infty$$

Comment: The second is easy, after a while $\sqrt{n}\ge 4$, so $\sqrt{n}^n\ge 4^n$. For the first, note that $n^{\sqrt{n}}=2^{\log_2(n)\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: @BenMillwood I've edited the question. I mean that I'm looking for the "technical motivation" (not things like "this grows bigger than that" and similar handwavings).

Comment: "This grows bigger than that" is pretty much what it *means* to have a limit of $\infty$, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can write 
$$n^{\sqrt{n}} = 2^{(\log_2 n) \sqrt{n} }$$
and
$${\sqrt{n}}^n = 2^{(\log_2 \sqrt{n}) n } =2^{ \frac12 (\log_2 n) n }. $$
Now  $(\log_2 n) \sqrt{n} $ is a lot smaller than $n$ for large $n$ while 
$\frac12 (\log_2 n) n $ is a lot larger than $n$ for large $n$.

Comment: Thank you. This is more like the type of motivation I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Set $x=\sqrt n$ for nicer notation. Then
$$n^{\sqrt n}-2^n = (x^2)^x - 2^{x^2} = (x^2)^x - (2^x)^x$$
and $2^x$ eventually grows to be a lot larger than $x^2$. This difference is only emphasized by raising to the $x$th power.

The other one is easier: $(\sqrt n)^n - 2^n$ becomes large as soon as $\sqrt n$ is larger than $2$.

Comment: I've expressedly asked for details and technical motivation. This handwaving doesn't fit the bill.

Comment: @user62029: It's not handwaving. Some details are omitted but some details must always be omitted: if you find particular details troublesome you should identify them explicitly.

Comment: @user62029 What part of Henning's proof are you finding difficult to understand?  If you aren't convinced that $2^x\gg x^2$, then perhaps try proving that $\frac{d}{dx}[2^x - x^2]>1$ for all $x$ greater than a certain point.  Thus, $(x^2)^x - (2^x)^x$ is unbounded from below.

Comment: In the first part we have an expression of the form $a^c-b^c$ where (eventually) $a>b>1$ and $c\ge 1$. In that case it is easy to see that $a^c-b^c \ge a-b$, so it is enough to prove that $a-b$ goes to infinity. The omitted step in the second part is the same, except with the opposite sign.